# А теперь о чукчах

Tags: этимология

Пока писала вопрос об инках, возник еще один - уже о чукчах.
Мне, собственно, интересно, почему их называют именно так, в такой форме? Самоназвание у них совершенно другое (я его не помню - какое-то труднопроизносимое для русского человека слово), но почему тогда не чукотцы, например? А то "чукча" звучит как-то... пренебрежительно, что ли. А ведь народ, несмотря на анекдоты, очень древний, самобытный и интересный!

Comment: Звучит  вполне  нейтрально.  Употребляется  в  пренебрежительном  смысле  в  русскоязычной  среде  очень  далекой  от  Чукотки  и  её  коренного  населения.  Кто среди  чукчей  живёт,  тот  может  и  не  пользуется  этим  словом.  Хотя  в  том,  что  этнонимы  могут  использоваться  в  негативном  смысле,  нет  ничего  нового  или  необычного.

Comment: Думаю,  что  слово "чукча"  вошло  в  русский  язык  не  из  чукотского,  а  из  языка  их  соседей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне, собственно, интересно, почему их
> называют именно так, в такой форме?

Скорее всего, Вики права: ***чукча*** -- от чукотского слова ***чаучу***  (богатый оленями). Похоже на то, что самим чукчам такое название не нравится.

> [В прошлом году] в Замоскворецкий суд
> был подан иск к... Большому толковому
> словарю. Скандал разгорелся вокруг
> приведенного в книге разговорного
> значения слова «чукча»: «наивный
> простодушный человек». Великий
> чукотский народ в лице певца
> Александра Тевлялькота, экс-депутата
> Госдумы Владимира Етылина и студента
> Виктора Нувано возмутился и пошел в
> суд. Иск, который сегодня
> рассматривали в Замоскворецком суде,
> подан к трем печатавшим словарь
> издательствам, редактору словаря
> Сергею Кузнецову и Институту
> лингвистических исследований РАН.
>
> Требования: изъять из библиотек и
> книжных магазинов весь тираж Большого
> толкового плюс по 5 миллионов рублей с
> каждого ответчика — в качестве
> моральной компенсации. Интересно, что
> словарь-то был издан еще в 1998 году.
> И возмущение зрело долгих 16 лет.
>
> - Деньги не главное, - объяснял перед судом Владимир Етылин, возглавляющий
>   движение «Возрождение Чукотки». - **Мы
>   вообще выступаем за то, чтобы слово
>   «чукча» всюду заменили на самоназвание
>   нашего народа - «лыгоравэтльан»...**
>
> http://www.kp.ru/daily/26235.5/3117768/

Comment: Пусть они на своём языке и самоназываются как угодно, а русский-то тут при чём? Непонятные люди.

Comment: "самоназвание" лыгоравэтльан  прекрасно читается по-русски - как сокращение,  лыжи ветер горы лань. Что в точности соответствует природе.

Точно также читается по-русски, к примеру, "самоназвание" - эрзянь раськенькоцт - рязанская русская кость.

Comment: Да, да, точно! Именно такое самоназвание я встречала в литературе, но не запомнила его. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Места эти исследовались при помощи морских судов, называемых  кочами.Название «Коч» связываюто со словом «коца» — шуба ледяная, то есть вторая ледовая обшивка судна.
В документах экспедиции Беринга впервые встречаются названия «Чукоцкий нос», видимо, либо ледяной, либо потому, что раньше другими судами уже проходили. Чу-это обратить внимание.
Чук-ча, житель Чукоцкого носа, скорее название произошло от чукоцы, что можно объяснить неправильным прочтением плохо записанной буквы ц, хвост чуть длиннее и читается как Ч, неудобное произношение сглотнули исключением буквы о и заменой ы на и.

Comment: Неубедительно  как-то!

Comment: Коч - судно класса река-море в сегодняшнем талышском, роськом языках.
На юго-западном побережье Каспийского моря в условиях субтропиков "ледяная шуба" - штука невозможная. 
Поморский коч, мог и замерзнуть, но вряд ли коч и "коца" одно слово.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ @petro. несомненно соответствует истине , -  указанием на **Чукоцкий Нос** из документов экспедиции Беринга . **Чукчи** (**Чук**+**ч** +а) суть жители территории Чукоцского Носа и прилегающих к нему . Но *ЧУ*=*Внимание* + *КОЧ* =*морское судно*  это уже фантазии  @petro. Те , кто был на старом сайте , наверняка помнят моё ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ о вариации/тождестве Ц-Ч . То есть топоним <<**Ч-укоцкий**>>  мог бы звучать и , как <<**Ц-укоцкий**>> . Скорее всего , это какой-то скальный мыс , - раз *Нос* . На иврите **צוּק** / **цук** означает - *утёс* , *скала* . Иврит использовался для новых географических названий точно так же , как латынь в медицине , фармакологии и систематике , а древнегреческий - в физике и математике .

[image: Ирис-словарь]